# Impedir que a página só seja mostrada quando todos os elementos da mesma forem carregados

Tags: javascript, front-end

Tenho uma página em html, em que listo dados, essa parte está assim:

```
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item 1</th>
                    <th>item 2</th>
                    <th>item 3</th>
                    <th>item 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {% for item in itens %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=""><img src="{{ item.att1 }}" width="50px" /></a></td>
                    <td><a href=""><strong>{{ item.att2 }}</strong></a></td>
                    <td><strong>{{ item.att3 }}</strong></td>
                    <td><strong style="color: green">{{ item.att4 }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Estou usando Django na minha aplicação.

O problema é o seguinte: os dados que estão sendo listados, são capturados no back-end e vem de um servidor externo, que muitas vezes atrasa muito o carregamento da página.

O que eu queria fazer era carregar toda a página (exceto a tabela), e enquanto isso poderia colocar uma mensagem qualquer para o usuário. E só depois quando todos os itens fossem carregados, a tabela seria exibida.

Andei pesquisando mas não encontrei nada relacionado. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: a tabela vem de um servidor externo certo? e você pega essa tabela via javascript, certo? então você poderia fazer o velho $(document).ready( function() {      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então Naldson, pra você fazer isso a solução é você carregar essa tabela com uma chamada assíncrona via JavaScript, ou seja, quando a página é carregada o seu JavaScript faz uma requisição Ajax ao servidor, seu ou externo, isso vai da sua arquitetura, e quando você obtiver essa resposta do server você monta a tabela adicionando as linhas e colunas dele com JavaScript também.

Aí caso você ache esse trabalho massante, procure estudar alguma lib JavaScript que facilite esse trabalho como jQuery, frameworks de componentes como React ou Vue.js, outros frameworks bem interessantes como AngularJS e Aurelia.